# How to use SQL query with a column of values for where?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I loop though a column of IDs I created with in a 2nd select query with a WHERE.

Example table of ids to loop through:

[image: 1]

Here is what I got so far:

```sql
WITH myTable  
AS (  
    select myKey as myKey  
    from dbo.table  
    Where column2 = 'x'  
    GROUP BY myKey  
)  
SELECT *  
FROM table2  
WHERE table2.key = myKey
```

I can't loop through table2 with my column of values. How can I do it?

Comment: join both tables.

Comment: Why do you want to "loop" at all? SQL is a set based language so looping is one of the last things you want to actually do. When writing SQL you want to implement set based operations, not iterative ones

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE table2.key IN (SELECT mt.myKey FROM myTable mt);
```

Given that the `mykey` is unique, you can also use `JOIN` and `EXISTS`.